# Error Refreshing Twitter Tweets

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, nsarray

My app is getting this error when refreshing twitter tweets:`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:`

Here is the code:

```
- (void)fetchInstagramPics {
    instaPics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL *status = [user boolForKey:@"isInstagramLoggedIn"];
    if (status) {
        [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:@"users/self/feed"
                                     parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                            // NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                                            self.timelineResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                                            [self.instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];
                                            [self updateArrays];
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
                                        }];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData]; });


}


- (void)updateArrays {
    instaPics = self.timelineResponse[@"data"];
    totalFeed = [tweets arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:instaPics];

}

- (void)fetchTimeline {
    [self fetchInstagramPics];
    [self fetchTweetsAuth];
    [self updateArrays];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)refetchTimeline {
    [self fetchInstagramPics];
    [self fetchTweets];
    [self updateArrays];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)fetchTweetsAuth {
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"4oFCF0AjP4PQDUaCh5RQ" secret:@"NxAihESVsdUXSUxtHrml2VBHA0xKofYKmmGS01KaSs"];

    [self.twitterClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"floadt://success"] accessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"POST" scope:nil success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/home_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
                tweets = responseArray;
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)fetchTweets{
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/home_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
                tweets = [tweets copy];
                tweets = responseArray;
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [self refetchTimeline];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

The `tweets` array is shared with a `instaPics` array which is under an array called `totalArray` Which is why I included the `fetchInstagramPics` function. I know it sounds complicated, but your help is deeply appreciated.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
STACK TRACE :
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x027978b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b6b3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02bf2365 -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 101
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02b2f2d0 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 208
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x02b2ef69 -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 425
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x02b2ed15 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 661
    7   MyApp                              0x0003c6c6 __42-[StreamViewController fetchInstagramPics]_block_invoke + 278
    8   MyApp                              0x0001e73b __64-[AFJSONRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke91 + 43
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x035187f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0352d4b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0351b75e _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd0a5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02b116bb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02b10ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02b108db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x045309e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x04530809 GSEventRun + 104
    18  UIKit                               0x0192ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    19  MyApp                              0x00062b1d main + 141
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x037bf70d start + 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `-[AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]`:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
#endif
```

In your AppDelegate in the bottom of file, below of all methods:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *ex)
{
    NSLog(@"CRASH :\n %@", ex.reason);
    NSLog(@"STACK TRACE :\n %@", ex.callStackSymbols);
    exit(0);
}
#endif
```

This way you will see stack trace in console. Afterwards you will now what function caused a crash and fix it, or edit your question by posting stacktrace to let us look at it.
**EDIT** After looking at your stack trace:
You do `[self.instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];`, however you make `instaPics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. I'm sure that your `self.instaPics` is immutable `NSArray`. I don't know, how your logic should work, you have to either `self.instaPics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` or `[instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I have added the stack trace with the default question